# Gamecube Controller Adapter not working

Tags: drivers, emulation, gamepad

I followed [this guide](https://seanyeh.com/pages/mayflash_gamecube_adapter_linux_dolphin_steam/) for getting my Gamecube controller/Mayflash adapter to work with Ubuntu (I'm on 22.04).  The program built correctly, but the adapter is not being detected in any programs in either PC or Switch/Wii U mode.  However, it does appear in the hardware list and works on gamepad-tester in PC mode. Has anyone else had trouble with this program? Does anyone have a solution?